# Sending string from android client to python server over socket

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I googled and saw almost all stackoverflow solutions and android documentation but I was unable to do it. Here is my server side code:-

```
import socket
import time

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#host = socket.gethostname()
host = "192.168.1.100"
port = 6000
serversocket.bind((host,port))

serversocket.listen(5)
def sample1():
    print "the data has arrived"
    clientsocket.send("success")

def sample2():
    print "the data"
    clientsocket.send("success again")

while True:
    clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

    while 1:
        data3 = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        data4 = data3.strip()
        if data4 == "hello":
            sample1()
        elif data4 == "hi":
            sample2()
        else:
            print "random data"
        if data4 == "stop":
            break
```

Here is my client code on android:-

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main22Activity extends Activity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.100";
TextView risp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main22);
    risp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    new ConnectionTask().execute();
}

class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String responce = null;
        try {
            String str = "hello";
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            out.println(str);
            out.flush();

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            int lockSeconds = 10*1000;

            long lockThreadCheckpoint = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int availableBytes = input.available();
            while(availableBytes <=0 && (System.currentTimeMillis() < lockThreadCheckpoint + lockSeconds)){
                try{Thread.sleep(10);}catch(InterruptedException ie){ie.printStackTrace();}
                availableBytes = input.available();
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[availableBytes];
            input.read(buffer, 0, availableBytes);
            responce = new String(buffer);

            out.close();
            input.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responce;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String responce) {
        risp.setText(responce);
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

onClick event is triggered on clicking a button. All permissions firewall settings also checked they are fine. On opening the app, it connects to python server (it shows it received a connection). On clicking, it sends string hello first which makes it jump to sample1 function and android also receives message success in textView. But after that it doesn't stop and python server keeps on printing random data forever and nothing happens on clicking the button again. I want my client to send hello only once after it is pressed, get the data, update UI and wait until button is pressed again. And originally, I am using this for raspberry pi to get temperature data so each time temperature changes, python server will send data and I want to display it on my android app without need of pressing any button. How should I do the thing I originally intend to do? Corrected code will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When the ConnectionTask completes, you close the socket. This means that you have to reopen it otherwise an Exception will be generated. An idea would be to place the code for opening the socket directly in the AsyncTask.

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't work.